# return a wide string from Win32::API call

Tags: windows, perl, utf-16le

I'm trying to figure out how to read the result of `GetCommandLineW` in Perl.

I know that is should return a string beginning with `"` when invoked under PowerShell, but I can't seem to extract more than one character.

The following snippet loads the `GetCommandLineW` function and attempts to invoke it.✱

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Win32;
use Data::Dumper;
use Win32::API;

my $GetCommandLineW = Win32::API::More->new(
  "kernel32", "LPWSTR GetCommandLineW()"
);
die unless $GetCommandLineW;

print Dumper($GetCommandLineW->Call());
```

prints

```
$VAR1 = '"';
```

I get the same thing if I replace `LPWSTR` in the command line with `char *` or anything else that's stringlike. I get back a pointer as a decimal number if I use `int` or a garbage value as the return type.

Is there a way that I can indicate to the `Win32::API` module that I am intending to read back a UTF-16 LE string or a way to "convince" it to put all the contents of said string into a Perl scalar.

I'm okay if there some encoding issues in the resulting scalar that need cleaning up immediately after calling `$GetCommandLineW->Call()` as long as all the data is there.

---

✱ The shebang is there so the same script can be invoked with or without Cygwin.